# put limit to bestseller product on homepage in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to limit the number of products  of bestseller on homepage in magento.

here is the bock code which I have used to display the bestseller products on home page

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list"  alias="products_homepage" limt="2"  category_id="4template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml"_ProductsCount="2"           _ColumnCount="2"}}
```

I had put limit but it is still not working.
Please tell me what's the wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried num_products?

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" num_products="2" column_count="2" template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml"}}
```